# Android Studio XML preview is blank

Tags: api, android-layout

Due to some unknown reasons the XML preview in my Android Studio is blank the code worked before no changes has been made there.The other Projects are working fine..Something is wrong in this one please help

-tried re installing Android Studio
-tried Cache and Restart Method

I think something is wrong with the API version in Editor as it is null and the only option available is "automatically pick best" where as for other projects a number of other options are available.

### Please Help!